# Android Studio Tabbed Activity: Where to put code for each tab?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

So I followed a tutorial online about creating a TabbedLayout in Android Studio. Everything went well and I did end of getting the TabbedLayout.

[image]

Above is my files. I have a java class and fragment for each tab, along with the MainActivity of course. But I don't know where to add code for each separate fragment or tab. I tried adding it to the corresponding java class but inside there is no onCreate method so I can't access findViewByID().

Below is what each tab java class looks like. 
[image]

I also tried doing it from the mainActivity (where I could access findViewByID) but my App kept force closing.

So I'm just not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `onViewCreated()` after onCreateView

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //here your code
    TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks that works, however when creating an onClick method in the fragment, no object on the fragment can recognize the method.

Comment: make sure you have the correct id.. try to log inside the onclick

Comment: I tried with no luck. The buttons just do the recognize the onclick